# Adding a remote do we call the remote name origin or upstream?

Tags: git

```
git version 1.8.5.3
```

Hello,

I have been using git for sometime now, and I have always cloned from another repository.

When I clone from a repository the default name for the remote is always `origin`.

However, I have created a new repository in my dropbox and initialized a bare repository as I want to push all my changes to it.

```
~/Dropbox/repos/netstatus.git
git init --bare
```

I have other computers I will work from; home computer and mobile computer. So I will clone on to these so I can do some work and push those changes.

However, my work computer is my main computer with all my initial work on for this project, and this is the one I will be doing most of my work from. So I have created a working directory with all my project files.

```
~/projects/netstatus
git init
```

I have added my files and directory for this project and created my first commit.

```
git add file1 file2 etc
git commit -am"Initial commit"
```

Now I want to add the remote in my dropbox so I can push my changes to it.

```
git remote add upstream ~/Dropbox/repos/netstatus.git
```

And on my home and mobile computer I will clone from here. which will give me the origin remote name after cloning.

My question is:
When I add the remote would I call the remote `origin` or `upstream`, as I have always cloned? I am not sure which one I should use.

Just a follow up question, in the steps above have I done anything incorrectly?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2):

As meagar posted: the remote name is just a name. It does not matter at all.

However, the convention is something like this:

- If you have a public/shared repo on github, dropbox, whereever. You clone it or make an initial push into it. That's normally `origin`.
- When there is a guy maintaining a repo, you want to contribute to. You fork it in public (like on github), than clone it to your local machine. Normally you would add the `upstream` remote repo to make to make updates easier. E.g. with `git pull upstream/master`.

**To sum things up:** In your case `origin` would be the appropriate name.

BTW: I'm not sure if this is still true, but dropbox and git do not behave well together.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. You can call it anything, it's just a convention. You can call it "origin" or "dropbox" or "myproject", it's just a name.

The other machines that you clone the repo on will still use "origin" as the name of the remote, regardless of what you call the remote on your desktop.

And no, nothing about the process you describe is incorrect, except that you made things slightly more difficult for yourself: You should have created the bare repo in dropbox, then cloned it to your desktop, so that a remote called "origin" was configured by default.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. The bare repository was created in my Dropbox. I guess what you are saying is create a bare repository. Then just clone it everywhere you want it. Sounds easy. However, when would we need to add a remote? Thanks.

Comment: Never, if you're starting from a base bare repository and cloning it a remote is setup for you automatically.